# Is there a linguistic term that describes words that change pronunciation when combined together?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, terminology

Examples of this include Breakfast which is just 'break,' and 'fast.'

Of particular interest to me is helicopter, which is a combination of 'helico,' meaning spiral, and 'pter,' meaning wing.

This is of special interest because helico would be pronounced 'heh-lee-kou,' while 'pter' would be pronounced 'tehr,'with a silent p. However, combined become 'heh-lee-kohp-tehr' instead of  'heh-lee-kou-tehr.'

Or even just copter, where the 'co' isn't even a proper prefix.

I suppose this could broadly fall under a portmanteau but I wonder if there's something more specific.

Comment: _Helico_ and _pter_ are not English words, but elements derived from Greek.

Comment: You need to differentiate between words with foreign roots like *helicopter* which (according to the OED) has always been pronounced in that (non-Greek) manner, and compound words which aren't pronounced the same as their English elements (often due to weakening of vowels or dropping of consonants), like *cupboard*, *forehead* (if you rhyme it with *horrid*), *breakfast*, etc.

Comment: The Greek roots got welded together too tight to break again, so _helicopter_ got re-split at a different joint, into _heli-: helipad, helicab_ and _-copter: cargocopter,_ etc.

Comment: _ELL_ has this question: [Why is there a pronunciation difference between “break” and “break”fast?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157547/why-is-there-a-pronunciation-difference-between-break-and-break-fast)

Comment: [linguistics.se] might be a better place to ask if they have a term for this phenomenon. It's just a specific case of words that have undergone pronunciation shifts (it's likely that it was originally pronounced as the constituent words).

Comment: @Barmar agreed. The question is clear but should be migrated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is clear but should be on the linguistics site.